# ¿Cómo obtener datos remotos desde el repositorio implementando el patrón MVVM propuesto por Android y usando el patrón singleton en Volley?

Tags: android, android-volley, mvvm

Estoy intentando integrar Volley singleton en un patrón MVVM. Según las recomendaciones de Android se debería usar un repositorio para manejar los datos desde diferentes fuentes (remota, local).

Para facilitar el trabajo he creado una clase singleton para las peticiones de red mediante Volley, dotando a dicha clase de un método para peticiones GET y de otro método para peticiones POST.

Esta es la clase singleton:

```
public class VolleyService {

    IResult mResultCallback = null;
    Context mContext;

    public VolleyService(IResult resultCallback, Context context){
        mResultCallback = resultCallback;
        mContext = context;
    }


    public void postDataVolley(final String requestType, String url, JSONObject sendObj){
        try {
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);

            JsonObjectRequest jsonObj = new JsonObjectRequest(url,sendObj, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    if(mResultCallback != null)
                        mResultCallback.notifySuccess(requestType,response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    if(mResultCallback != null)
                        mResultCallback.notifyError(requestType,error);
                }
            });

            queue.add(jsonObj);

        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }

    public void getDataVolley(final String requestType, String url){
        try {
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
            JsonObjectRequest jsonObj = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d("VolleyService", "RESPONSE:Volley requester iniRepo"+response.toString() );

                    if(mResultCallback != null)
                        mResultCallback.notifySuccess(requestType, response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("VolleyService", "ERROR:Volley requester iniRepo"+error.toString() );

                    if(mResultCallback != null)
                        mResultCallback.notifyError(requestType, error);
                }
            });

            queue.add(jsonObj);

        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
}
```

He implementado también una interfaz:

```
public interface IResult {
    public void notifySuccess(String requestType, JSONObject response);
    public void notifyError(String requestType, VolleyError error);
}
```

Luego, según he entendido, los datos que vengan desde la red deberían ser obtenidos en el repositorio. Para ello he hecho lo siguiente:

1. Crear un constructor adicional en la clase de repositorio para tener una referencia de la aplicación, para tener el contexto, el cual es necesario para las peticiones Volley. No sé si es la mejor forma de hacerlo.
2. Tratar de obtener los datos remotos usando la clase singleton de Volley. Esto es lo que no funciona.

A manera de prueba he creado un método simple, el cual llamo desde `loadProduct()`, pero la petición Volley no ocurre y no sé por qué.

Esta es mi clase de repositorio completa:

```
public class DataRepository {

    private static DataRepository sInstance;

    private AppDatabase mDatabase;
    private MediatorLiveData<List<ProductEntity>> mObservableProducts;
    Application application;

    private DataRepository(final AppDatabase database) {
        mDatabase = database;
        mObservableProducts = new MediatorLiveData<>();

        mObservableProducts.addSource(mDatabase.productDao().loadAllProducts(),
                productEntities -> {
                    if (mDatabase.getDatabaseCreated().getValue() != null) {
                        mObservableProducts.postValue(productEntities);
                    }
                });
    }
    private DataRepository(Application application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    public static DataRepository getInstance(final AppDatabase database) {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            synchronized (DataRepository.class) {
                if (sInstance == null) {
                    sInstance = new DataRepository(database);
                }
            }
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    /**
     * Get the list of products from the database and get notified when the data changes.
     */
    public LiveData<List<ProductEntity>> getProducts() {
        return mObservableProducts;
    }

    public LiveData<ProductEntity> loadProduct(final int productId) {
        Log.d("fromRepo", "ok");
        //Only for test
        initVolleyCallback();
        return mDatabase.productDao().loadProduct(productId);
    }

    public LiveData<List<CommentEntity>> loadComments(final int productId) {
        return mDatabase.commentDao().loadComments(productId);
    }

    public LiveData<List<ProductEntity>> searchProducts(String query) {
        return mDatabase.productDao().searchAllProducts(query);
    }

    /*
       I created this method only for test
       It's not working here
    */
    public  String initVolleyCallback(){
        Log.d("VolleyFromRepo", "ok");
        IResult mResultCallback = null;
        VolleyService mVolleyService = new VolleyService(mResultCallback,application);
        mVolleyService.getDataVolley("GETCALL","myURLHere");
        return "ok";
    }

}
```

Para probar, llamo a `loadData()` desde mi Activity, pero no está funcionando:

```
LiveData<ProductEntity> liveData = getRepository().loadProduct(2);
liveData.observe(this, m -> {
    Log.d(TAG, m.getDescription());
});
```

No es problema de `loadProduct()`, pues puedo ver el log de `m.getDescription()`, y puedo ver también el log de `VolleyFromRepo`, pero no veo los datos (en la clase singleton he puesto logs para mostrar la respuesta y el error y nada de eso ocurre, es como si no estuvieran bien conectados los elementos).

Si pongo el mismo método en mi Activity la petición a Volley mediante la clase singleton sí funciona:

```
/*
   From activity it's working
   I can see the logs
*/
void initVolleyCallback(){
    IResult mResultCallback = null;
    mVolleyService = new VolleyService(mResultCallback,this);
    mVolleyService.getDataVolley("GETCALL","myURLHere");

}
```

¿Qué es lo que está mal en mi código? ¿Por qué la petición Volley no está funcionando en la clase del repositorio? Si he entendido algo mal, agradezco sus correcciones al respecto, apenas empiezo con el patrón MVVM.

Comment: No veo el código de tu viewmodel, se supone que si vas a usar MVVM debes crear un viewmodel, en ese viewmodel se hace el llamado a tu clases que se encargan de darte los datos local y remotos (repository), echale una mirada a este proyecto:https://github.com/android/sunflower/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/sunflower